# Limit behaviour and integral of a density

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, probability-distributions

Let $g \in \mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is the set of all the Lebesgue absolutely continuous probability densities on $\mathbb{R}^m$ invariant under orthogonal transformations. Then, let us define $\tilde{g}:\mathbb{R}_0^{+} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ as
\begin{equation*}
g(\mathbf{x}) = \tilde{g}(||\mathbf{x}||^2) = \tilde{g}(t), \forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m. 
\end{equation*}

If $\textstyle\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{m/2-1} \tilde{g}(t)dt < \infty$, is it possible to show that:
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty }t^{m/2} \tilde{g}(t)  = 0 ?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Not possible since the statement is not true. Construct a function of the form $\sum_na_n\mathbb{1}_{A_n}$ where the $n^{m/2-1}a_n\nearrow\infty$ and the length of $A_n$ is very small to make $\sum_na_nn^{m/2-1}|A_n|<\infty$.

Comment: Is there any "regularity condition" to put on g in order to make the statement true? I found this result in a paper, but no details are given...